# PhpStorm 9 Live templates import

Tags: templates, phpstorm, live

I found these useful Live Templates for PhpStorm 9 for Laravel Framework:

https://github.com/koomai/phpstorm-laravel-live-templates

but I can't find a folder like this

> ~/Library/Preferences/product name - version number/templates

to import these files.

I am working with OSX Yosemite

Thx for help!!

Comment: So what folders do you have there in `~/Library/Preferences/`? If anything -- https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206827437-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs

Comment: Audio/                     SystemConfiguration/     
DirectoryService/          Xsan/                    
OpenDirectory/             com.sophos.swc.persisted/  -- I also found that list with possible PRODUCT names but no match :/

Comment: For PhpStorm v9.0.x the folder should be `~/Library/Preferences/WebIde90/templates`, for 9.5 (currently at EAP stage) it should be `~/Library/Preferences/WebIde95/templates`. If unable to find -- do a global search for `WebIde90`

Comment: Thanks for the help, but global  search givrs no result (also for WebIde).. strange thing. Maybe it is possible to set that path manually?

Comment: Maybe you are looking in the wrong place? or folder is hidden? Sorry for dumb question -- are you sure you are using PhpStorm and it is installed on this system/user and not in VM/other user? In any case: try checking `idea.log` file (`Help | Show Log in...`). As for changing default directories -- https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206827407-Changing-IDE-default-directories-used-for-config-plugins-and-caches-storage

Comment: I may suggest you this: go and create custom keymap in Preferences -- give it a unique name (e.g. `abcabcabc`); exit IDE completely and search for such file (e.g. `abcabcabc.xml`)

Comment: Hey, sorry... my fault. From the console I typed like "cd /Library/...." but I found the dir now in "cd ~/Library/..."   :/ so the dumb question "solved" the problem.. thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For PhpStorm v9.0.x the folder should be `~/Library/Preferences/WebIde90/templates`, for 9.5 (currently at EAP stage) it should be `~/Library/Preferences/WebIde95/templates`. If unable to find -- do a *global search* for `WebIde90`.

Double check the path you are checking: `~/Library` is not the same as `/Library` (first one located in your user folder, so the real path would be something like `/Users/USER_NAME/Library...`).